# How can I eliminate same characters with same index between two strings?

Tags: python, character, cpu-word

For example, two strings are given as `"hello"` and `"sello"` 
(or it also can be a list like `["h","e","l","l","o"]` and `["s","e","l","l","o"]`
It removes the same characters with the same index between two strings.

After the elimination loop, it should return `"h"` and `"s"` respectively.

And for example, two strings are given as `"sony"` and `"nani"` 
then it should return `"soy"` and `"nai"`

Comment: you loop through both list and compare, if match then remove that index from the list and join them again into string

Comment: @Sayse Sorry but I don't understand your point. "sony" / "nani" result in "soy" / "nai" after eliminating the same letter "n" with index 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "hello"
b = "hallo world"
if len(a)>len(b):
strLen = len(b)
else:
strLen = len(a)
for i in range(strLen):
if a[i]==b[i]:
  a = a[:i] + a[(i+1):]
  b = b[:i] + b[(i+1):]
  i--;
  strLen--;
```

you just get the string by index and compare them one by one, and remove them.
But you after remove one of them, you need to i-- as the next char index become the current one.
Also if you dont want to eliminate spaces, you can add one more condition to check if the current index in string is not a spaces

Comment: ops, my bad, i missed it

Comment: Then I suggest you would delete this answer, as it's not what was asked, and could not be directly translated to `python`, where one can not change the iterator `i` inside the loop, or remove char from a string directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone would post something more straight-forward, but this works:

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'sello'
for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        a = [c if j != i else '' for j, c in enumerate(a)]
        b = [c if j != i else '' for j, c in enumerate(b)]
a = ''.join(a) # OUTPUT 'h'
b = ''.join(b) # OUTPUT 's'
```

Comment: Thanks. The implementation was more complicated than I expected.